# mod_rewrite apache FQDN to Hostname

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to find a mod_rewrite code for forcing users that go to FQDN to be re-written to the hostname without the domain and don't want them to be stuck in a loop. I can only find re-write examples for the other way round. Anyone have a suggestion on how I can do this?

So example if I was to go to `http://appname.example.com/test.php`

The rewritten URL should be `http://appname/test.php`

Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: "re-written to the hostname without the domain" - What do you mean by this? Please give an example of the URL that should be redirected from/to.

Comment: @MrWhite i've updated with an example

Comment: Is this on a local network? Is `appname` registered as a _hostname_ on the local network (in a local DNS/HOSTS file)?

Comment: It's on a local network with the hostname on the DNS

Comment: `appname.example.com` is not a FQDN, it's simply a subdomain. Is the `appname` variable? As written, this looks like an ordinary domain redirect?

Comment: "I can only find re-write examples for the other way round." - The principle would be the same. Do you have a reference to an example that is the "other way round"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To "redirect" `http://<appname>.example.com/<url-path>` to `http://<appname>/<url-path>` (where `<appname>` and `<url-path>` are entirely variable and `<appname>` is also a resolvable hostname on the local network) then you would do something like the following using mod_rewrite at the top of the root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)([a-z-]+)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

This excludes the `www` subdomain using a negative lookahead.

`%1` in the *substitution* string is a backreference to the `<appname>` as captured from the requested *hostname*.

`%{REQUEST_URI}` contains the full root-relative URL-path (starting with a slash).

This also handles FQDN (that end in a dot).